# Statistic to best summarize changing price level over an interval?

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, price-discrimination

You are told that in a given week `4` of a given good are sold at a price of `100` and `6` of the same good are sold at a price of `80`. You need to summarize your sales and price for the week. You ought to report your quantity sold as `10 [= 4 + 6]`. What price level is best to associate with this quantity sold?

One way to approach this is to take the weighted average a contribution to sales:

`80 * 6/10 + 100 * 4/10 = 88 =` summary price

Another way is to take the weighted average as a contribution to revenue:

`80*6 = 480` ; `100*4 = 400`; `480 + 400 = 880 =` net revenue

`80 * 480/880 + 100 * 400/880 = 89.09 =` summary price

I am feeding this data to an AI model which is predicting quantity sold in a given week. My data is provided in days.

It is worth mentioning that if I were to compute the demand line between points `(4,100)` and `(10,80)` (where `10 = 4 + 6` ) I would get `y = -20x/6 + 113.3`. Neither point `(10,88)` nor `(10, 89.09)` are on this line.

Comment: Instead of using only two points, you should use the whole sample (10 data points) to estimate the linear demand. The data points are $(1,100), (2,100),\dots,(4,100), (5,80), (6,80),\dots,(10,80)$.

Comment: I decided to just think of the price values as a distribution and take a weighted (by quantity) mean.

Comment: Why are we using monospace code format for equations?

Comment: What does monospace code format mean in this context?